# $4$-form $ \omega \wedge  \omega$ vanishes on $S^4$

Tags: differential-topology, manifolds, differential-forms, symplectic-geometry

If $\omega$  is a closed $2$-form on $S^4$, how can I show the $4$-form $ \omega \wedge  \omega$  vanishes somewhere on $S^4$?  I am guessing that the fact we're talking about the $2$-form being closed, that this is the crux.

Comment: The *symplectic-geometry* tag is a bit cryptic here :) But this is connected to the proof that $S^4$ is not a symplectic manifold.

Answer (score 10):

Obviously $d(\omega\wedge\omega)=0$, so that $\omega\wedge\omega$ represents an element of $H^4(S^4)$.

*Suppose $\omega\wedge\omega$ is never zero*. Then it is a volume form and therefore its class in $H^4(S^4)$ is *not* zero.

Now, since $d\omega=0$ and $H^2(S^4)=0$, there is a $1$-form $\eta$ such that $d\eta=\omega$. Then $d(\eta\wedge\omega)=\omega\wedge\omega$ and $\omega\wedge\omega$ is a coboundary. This is absurd.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that this is a variant of the argument showing that the only even-dimensional sphere admitting a symplectic structure is $S^2$.

Comment: Isn't it *the* argument?

Comment: People like to use Stokes to show that a symplectic form on a closed manifold is never exact: $$
0 \neq \int_{M} \omega \wedge \omega = \int_{M} d(\eta \wedge \omega) = \int_{\partial M} \eta \wedge \omega = 0
$$
and similarly in higher dimensions. Not *very* different, yes.

Comment: Ah, right. The argument I wrote down uses the fact that the sphere is a sphere, of course ;)